# prevent fixed element from moving on smartphone

Tags: javascript, css, ios, iphone, overflow

I have the following snippet working except when you scroll to the bottom of the #section-container the fixed element at the top moves.  How can I prevent that from happening ***on a smart phone?***

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: orange;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
}

#container {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position:sticky;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 20%;
  background-color: purple;
}

#fixed {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position:sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#section-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.sections {
  height: 100%;
}

#section1,
#section3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#section2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
  <title>scroll</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id='fixed'>

  </div>
  <div id='container'>

    <div id='section-container'>
      <div id='section1' class='sections'>

      </div>
      <div id='section2' class='sections'>

      </div>
      <div id='section3' class='sections'>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: remove position:fixed; and top:0; from the html and body sections of your css for a start

Comment: doesn't make a difference

Comment: it will when you change your lightblue section to position:sticky instead of fixed (in addition. Your body and html will always start at the top anyway, and absolutely positioning never works in responsive design anyway. position should only be applied to elements within the body

Comment: @Rachel Gallen thanks for taking the time to answer but your suggestions aren't really helping.  It would help if you tested out your suggestions first to make sure they work.

Comment: Is this safari specific ?

Comment: no, it should work for any web browser

Comment: No i mean the issue because i don't see it moving in chrome or FF

Comment: are you using a smartphone to view?

Comment: Oh i think i see it, it's the browser's toolbar that gets shifted upward when you reach the bottom even the answer you provided doesn't solve it.

Comment: @Zohir Salak my answer works fine on my iphone 6.  What are you viewing it on?

Comment: Chrome android 9 Nexus 5

Comment: are you sure the js loaded?

Comment: Yes, the original code alone works if i scroll the whole page first but then i make the toolbar appear again by randomly scrolling upward from anywhere on the page and it'll get messed up again. it's just the quirk with the browser toolbar, i don't think you should worry too much about it

Answer (score 0):

I found a js library called bodyScrollLock that works. Seems like a lot of overhead to do something this simple.  Does anyone have a more native solution?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" >
        <title>scroll</title>
        <script src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/js/bodyScrollLock.min.js?test0=xxx"></script>
        <style>
            html{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                background-color:orange;
            }
            body{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
            }
            #container{
                position: -webkit-sticky;
                position:sticky;
                height:80%;
                width:100%;
                top:20%;
                background-color:purple;
            }
            #fixed{
                position: -webkit-sticky;
                position:sticky;
                top:0;
                height:20%;
                width:100%;
                background-color:lightblue;
            }
            #section-container{
                height:100%;
                overflow:scroll;
                
            }
            .sections{
                height:100%;
            }
            #section1,#section3{
                background-color:blue;
            }
            #section2{
                background-color:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id='myBody'>
        <div id='fixed'>
                
        </div>
        <div id='container'>
            
            <div id='section-container'>
                <div id='section1' class='sections'>
                    
                </div>
                <div id='section2' class='sections'>
                    
                </div>
                <div id='section3' class='sections'>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            const scrollElement = document.getElementById('section-container');
            bodyScrollLock.disableBodyScroll(scrollElement);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```